# Navigating to a lightning app--what's the URL?

Tags: lightning-apps, url, app-builder

How would one navigate between lightning apps using the Salesforce1 javascript functions?

I see actions for navigateToURL and navigateToSobject, etc, but not NavigateToLightningApp?

Comment: is there any solution or work around for it? I have the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation on pageReference types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) it is possible to navigate to an app using URLs with the app's developer name such as `/lightning/app/standard__LightningSales`.

A few other examples from the documentation:

**URL Format**

`/lightning/app/{appTarget}{...pageRef}`

**URL Format Examples**

Navigate to the app's homepage using the appId

`/lightning/app/06mRM0000008dNrYAI`

Navigate to an object record's page in the app using the appId

`/lightning/app/06mRM0000008dNrYAI/o/Case/home`

Navigate to the app's homepage using the appDeveloperName

`/lightning/app/standard__LightningSales`

Navigate to an object record's page in the app using the `appDeveloperName`

`/lightning/app/standard__LightningSales/o/Case/home`

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Apps are meant to be single page Apps, not multi-page apps. If a means were available to navigate from one app to another other than through the SF1 Menu, that would effectively make them multi-page apps. To the best of my knowledge, what you're asking for does not exist at this time.

Comment: not buying that one.  Gmail and Gcal are SPAs, but I can navigate between them without issue.  Since there's a SF1 "tab", and I can hit reload in the /one/one.app option, it has a URL somewhere.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but SF hasn't added the functionality you speak of at this time. There's clearly an underlying Menu Command that will take you to an Object that's similar to `navigateToSObject` or `navigateToList`, but there isn't an equivalent when it's a Lightning page unless you use an Action.

Comment: I'd settle for how to parse the url schema, then we could use navigateToURL()

Comment: But as you already know, navigateToURL() won't work for you. You've got to get to the lightning subdomain to use it and I don't believe it will allow you to do that other than via an Action.

Comment: is there any information recently about this topic?

Comment: Actually, I believe there may be. With W16, Salesforce released an App Launcher component for App Builder to allow you to navigate between apps. See the [W16 Release Notes for more details](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_applauncher.htm). Whatever SF did inside that component would allow you to navigate to another app.

Answer (score 0):

`navigateToComponent` was the closest we had, and it's gone now. Right now your only option is to mount your Lightning Page or Component as a tab, and handle all navigation yourself by dynamically creating the components you desire.

Coming soon (hopefully) will be the ability to mount a lightning component as a `recordTab` or as a quick action, but we don't have that yet.

Comment: any new news for this topic now? I mean this would be a really useful feature because, in this moment, I have multi-pages and we moving from one to another in VisualForce classic.